# How do I convert a json field of nested arrays into a Java entity?

Tags: java, arrays, twitter-streaming-api

I have a `json` from the `Twitter Stream API`. A field in this json consists of a `nested` array.

This json field looks like this:

```
{
"bounding_box": {
"coordinates": [
  [
    [
      -74.026675,
      40.683935
    ],
    [
      -74.026675,
      40.877483
    ],
    [
      -73.910408,
      40.877483
    ],
    [
      -73.910408,
      40.3935
    ]
  ]
],
"type": "Polygon"
}
}
```

I create a java class called BoundingBox, and in it I define a variable of the type coordinates. What type should this variable have?

I need help with how to turn this space into a Java object. Can you please help me?

Comment: are you using any library to parse this json?

Comment: @michalk yes i'm using `google gson` for parse json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your `coordinates` property is three dimensional array so to parse it you would have to use for example `List<List<List<Double>>>`. Your `BoundingBox` class could look like this :

```
public class BoundingBox {
    private List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates;
    private String type;
    // constructors, getters, setter
}
```

Personally I think that storing data in three nested lists is a bad approach and you should think how to logically arrange those data. Maybe the most nested list represent x, y coordinates of some location and you could create another POJO that would actually make your data model more readable.